# Refit's Default behavior for object in post method without [body]

Tags: refit

I am reading Refit's https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#body-content document and understand what Body attribute when used for the 4 possibilities.

My question is for the example in above document, what is the behavior if I take the Body attribute from the "user" object. Will the user still be sent as the HTTP POST request body to the remote service endpoint? Per my limited search I could not find references directly explaining this scenario.

```
[Post("/users/new")]
Task CreateUser(User user); // w/o [Body] attribute
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any references to back this up, but it looks like Refit will map C# parameters to URL parameters by default.